# Remove a particular token from a string in an array

Tags: java

I’m trying to remove the first part of the string which I have listed in the array named Tokens. I have looked at other examples but those are for just a singular string. This is the code I have:

```
String s = “# hello 1234”;

String[] tokens = {“# hello”, “# bye”};

s = s.substring(s.indexOf(String.valueOf(tokens)) + tokens.length);

System.out.print(s);
```

Output wanted: 1234
Output I’m getting : hello 1234

Comment: Can you clarify because it seems like tokens is an array of strings none of which have the numbers 1234 in them.

Comment: @goodies4uall I want to retain the 1234 and remove the # hello

Comment: @alwaysStuckJava Then that has nothing to do with your tokens. You just want to extract the integer out from the String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you everything after the token

```
    String s = "# hello 1234";

    String[] tokens = {"# hello", "# bye"};

//s = s.substring(s.indexOf(String.valueOf(tokens)) + tokens.length);

    for (String token : tokens) {
        String[] split;
        if(s.contains(token)) {
            split = s.split(token);
            s = split[1].trim();
        }
    }

    System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you

Comment: Wow, it seriously helps? I see major flaws in it.

Comment: There is many flaws with this depending on many different variables if there are multiple tokens in the string as well as many other things this will only work in small scenarios

Comment: I take `s` as an example only. I can write even simplier code that works for `s = "# hello 1234"`, for example just `s = "1234"` would also work.

Comment: From what i understood he wanted to remove anything from before the token which is why I used split and the trim is used for pulling off the white space

Comment: Ah ... sorry then. Well, anyway, removing a token from the start of a string could call for even simpler solutions. Especially depending on what are the possible inputs.

Comment: Your solution is fine then, though, unless the token appears multiple times in the string. Which is also unspecified ... well, I downvoted the question already.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Matt. I’m really sorry @Vlasec to upset you so so greatly and I hope you manage to find happiness in another thread.

Comment: @alwaysStuckJava It's OK, just try to specify the input better next time.

Comment: Maybe also if this will be implemented in a project or a one time thing